# How to fit n features in a number of neurons smaller than n

Tags: neural-network, classification, features

Suppose I have a feature composed by 784 numbers, and I want to use it as input of a neural network implemented from scratch whose first layer has 64 neurons.

How can I put 784 numbers in 64 neurons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reduce the number of features from the raw data to 64 input neurons, you can perform [dimensionality reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction). There are various methods to do this, here are some common ones that are easy to implement.

1. [Principle Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)
2. [Autoencoders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) (basically another neural network that you can train unsupervised)
3. [Random projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_projection) (Make a 784x64 random matrix and multiply)